# Xtend: Generators produce comma instead of point

Tags: java, templates, generator, code-generation, xtend

I am using template expressions for generating files. For example:

```
def generateStuff(MyObject in) {
    '''
    This is the wrong value: «calculatedoubleValue(in.doubleValue)»
    '''
}
```

The value of `doubleValue` is an `double`. But the generator produces a comma instead of an point, as delimiter.

I also tried using `DecimalFormat`, for example:

```
def generateStuff(MyObject in) {
    var df = new DecimalFormat("0.000");
    var calculated = calculatedoubleValue(in.doubleValue)
    '''
    This is the wrong value: «df.format(calculated)»
    '''
}
```

But unfortunately it still produces a comma. I wonder, because it only happens to a few values and not to all, allthough I am only working with `double`s. Another strange thing is, that it produces points, when debugging (Runtime Eclipse Application) but commas after I export the application as an Eclipse product.

What could be the cause for this?

Answer (score 0):

Within template expressions toString() is invoked on any values (see [StringConcatenation](https://github.com/eclipse/xtext/blob/master/plugins/org.eclipse.xtext.xbase.lib/src/org/eclipse/xtend2/lib/StringConcatenation.java#L183)). 
Double.toString will always use '.', so the issue must be somewhere else.
Maybe the problem is in your 'calculatedDouble' method?

Comment: Sven, thank you very much for the quick answer. I wonder why it works, during debugging (Runtime Eclipse Application) but not after exporting the Eclipse product. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Although I don't have much info about your environment, based on your example code you do not directly use Double.toString() (that always uses `.` as decimal separator) but `DecimalFormat` which is locale-sensitive.

When `DecimalFormat` is constructed by using the [DecimalFormat(String)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html#DecimalFormat-java.lang.String-), it will use the default "format locale". In some locales the decimal separator is `.` (e.g. in English) but in other locales it is `,` (e.g. in Hungarian). See the [API docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) for more details.

Proposed solutions to your problem:

- Ensure that the application uses the same locale in each case.
- Set the locale-specific formatting options explicitly.

Real code:

```
@Test
public void testDecimalFormat() {
    assertEquals("0.000", new DecimalFormat("0.000", new DecimalFormatSymbols(Locale.ENGLISH)).format(0.0));
    assertEquals("0,000", new DecimalFormat("0.000", new DecimalFormatSymbols(new Locale("hu"))).format(0.0));
}
```